# Django - Cannot resolve keyword 'count_number' into field when I use values_list

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

There is a query:

```
selected = MyModel.objects.filter(category_id=category_id,status__gte=0) \
               .filter(pub_time__lte=_refresh_datetime,
                       buy_links__status=2) \
               .annotate(like_count=Count('likes'))\
               .order_by('-like_count')
```

it works, but, When I need to get id of this query:

```
selected_id_list = selected.values_list('id')
```

Raised:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'like_count' into field. Choices are: ....

Anyone knows about this?

ps,

Python version: 2.7.10

Django version: 1.6.11

Comment: It looks like the query is optimised more at that point so its ordered before annotate.. is it an option to upgrade your django? it may be resolved in newer versions

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for your reply. I'm sure It's didn't optimised, and I can't upgrade the django, it is on live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `values_list('id', 'like_count')`. I don't know Django much, but the annotated filed must appear in the SELECT expression. It looks like with `values_list('id')`, the generated query becomes `SELECT id FROM ...`, in which case `count(likes)` is missing from the SELECT expression.

In sum, `selected_id_list = [r[0] for r in selected.values_list('id', 'like_count')]`